# How do I set the folders for Pictures, Desktop etc?

Tags: 11.04, directory

When I installed Natty from scratch, I decided to install it in my native language instead of English. It detected that I had folders like Pictures etc in my home folder, and prompted me if I wanted to use the Norwegian equivalent instead. However, it didn't rename the existing folders, it merely created new ones and ignored all my data.

I know I can move the data myself, but I would rather continue to use the old directories so I don't have to update my backups etc. How do I change them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Tweak has a simple interface for accomplishing this. You can download it [here](http://www.ubuntu-tweak.com).